# Can an LL(0) language have more than one word in it?

Tags: parsing, compiler-theory

I have the following simple question: If a language is LL(0), can
it have more than one word in it ?

I think that the answer is no, since if there were two words, you
can't read them to tell which one to derive

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from definition:

> An LL parser is called an LL(k) parser if it uses k tokens of lookahead when parsing a sentence

and definition of lookahead:

> Lookahead establishes the maximum incoming tokens that a parser can use to decide which rule it should use.

Assume that your language is flow of random commands without any dependency between each other - then you can have  as many words as you want.

**EDITED**
Using bison notation:

```
%token A B
%start single

single: A | B;
```

So you don't need to lookahead at all, but this grammar includes 2 words A,B

Comment: I don't think I understand. Can you please give an example of a grammar which is LL(0) but can derive more than 1 terminal word ?